# Truffle Tutorial pet-shop with test-rpc adopt button doesn't work

Tags: truffle, testrpc, metamask

I have followed the tutorial exactly like they showed in their page: 
 http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop
except the following changes because they use "ganache" (currently bugged and unavailable) and I chose "test-rpc":
In "truffle.js" port: 8545
In "src/app.js" App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545');
The "adopt" button in the front-end UI doesn't prompt the transaction with metamask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue because of a misplaced "view" classification. Please see https://github.com/trufflesuite/trufflesuite.com/pull/52 and it should work.
"Removed the "view" word from line 130. With the word view in there, you can never click the adopt button and MetaMask will never pop up."