# truffle pet shop example - metamask connects but adopt button not working

Tags: truffle

I am having some trouble with getting the adopt button to work in the truffle pet shop tutorial:

https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop

I have worked through the truffle petshop example twice from scratch and I have also looked at the proposed solution here:

[Truffle Tutorial pet-shop with test-rpc adopt button doesn't work](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34263/truffle-tutorial-pet-shop-with-test-rpc-adopt-button-doesnt-work)

However, I find that metamask is connecting to my petshop application but the adopt button is not doing anything. I've hosted the app here for now:

http://www.snipperly.com:3000/

To avoid typos, I have copied and pasted code from the truffle site into my files. May I ask how this could be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this answer to this

The error I was making what that I was deploying to a localhost on a virtual private server (ubuntu) but my metamask was set to Ropsten (on windows)

I resolved this by deploying to Ropsten using these helpful tutorials

https://medium.com/coinmonks/5-minute-guide-to-deploying-smart-contracts-with-truffle-and-ropsten-b3e30d5ee1e

https://www.masonforest.com/blockchain/ethereum/2017/11/13/how-to-deploy-an-erc20-token-in-20-minutes.html